# Does downgrading Lion to Snow Leopard also downgrade firmware?

Tags: macos, wifi

Ever since I installed Lion I've had problems with wifi. Connections would drop, and once wifi was turned off it wouldn't turn back on. Now, I can't use it at all - it says "No hardware installed."

The same problem also exists in Windows on my Boot Camp partition, so I think it's a firmware or hardware issue. I'd like to fix it by downgrading to Snow Leopard, but would this also downgrade the wifi firmware?

Comment: Did you consider a hardware failure already?

Answer (score 5):

No. Firmware is outside the scope of traditional OS updates (e.g., 10.7.2). On Macs, there is actually no way to revert a firmware update (even if you download a prior revision).